# Adding "InputText" to existing link?

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-formula, powerapps-selected-items

First question I have asked on Stackoverflow and looking for some advice/ help.

I am using Powerapps to provide a front end that will allow the end users to search for a document and then be able to see it/ open it.

I am sure it is possible but I just can't see it at the moment. Essentially I wan't whatever they put in the search box to append the url.

For example:

https://example.com/documents/"searchinput".pdf

Obviously I want the "searchinput" part to be whatever they input in the text field but I am not sure how to complete this in Power Apps.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Note the name of the text input box where you enter your search input ( you can find it under tree view  at left side of Powerapps screen).

Now create a **HTML text** option which can be found at Insert->Text.

After creating one, you will have a property *HtmlText* enter "Check PDF" or any instruction for the end user you wish to provide.

Then go for *OnSelect* property and enter

```
Launch( "https://example.com/documents/" & "text_input_box_name" & ".pdf")
```

Comment: SAVIOUR! Thank you! I tried various combinations of similar things but It didn't quite work so thank you for this! It works now I just need to Doll it up and make it pretty thank you